# Not able to understand typedef pointer function declaration in OBS-Studio source code

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, typedef, obs-studio

I understand typedef function pointer like

```
typedef   void          (*myType)    ( );
//         ^                ^         ^
//     return type      type name  arguments

myType x;
void myFunc() { std::cout<<"Hello\n"; }
x = &myFunc;

x(); // will print "Hello"
```

But I am not able to understand this line from [OBS Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) source code at
https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture/blob/master/source/external/IVideoCaptureFilter.h

```
//! Message callback
typedef void (CALLBACK* PFN_VIDEO_CAPTURE_FILTER_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK)(VIDEO_CAPTURE_FILTER_NOTIFICATION nMessage, void* pData, int nSize, void* pContext);
```

I am not able to understand why `CALLBACK*` and `PFN_VIDEO_CAPTURE_FILTER_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK` are together in `()` and what should I understand by this declaration?

Comment: These things are macros obviously.

Comment: `CALLBACK` is probably MACRO to set calling convention.